# Check RSS feed titles for words. Print only titles that contain word

Tags: python, regex, rss

I am trying to build an RSS-Parser that will check each title for keywords. So I only get the feeds that I am interested in. Thus far I am able to get the titles using regex. But I am unsure on how to proceed. I would like to check the titles for multiple keywords, so it would be best to load them from a .txt file. I only want those titles to be printed out that have a positive match. Can someone    point me in the right direction?

My code so far:

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import re
import cookielib
from cookielib import CookieJar
import time
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

def main():
    try:
        page = 'http://randomdomainXYZ.com/news-feed.xml'
        sourceCode = opener.open(page).read()
        #print sourceCode

        try:
            titles = re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)</title>', sourceCode)
            for title in titles:
                print title

        except Exception, e:
            print str(e)

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to print titles that contain one of the words in some list.  Try:

```
for title in titles:
    if any(word in title for word in word_list):
        print title
```

As for reading your word list, you can read all the lines in a file with:

```
with open('word_list.txt') as f:
    word_list = f.readlines()

# Make sure words don't end with a newline character ('\n')
word_list = [word.strip() for word in word_list]
```

Comment: I wonder if this should be done with some regex though. So it will find words inside words, lets say "Lifeinsurance" and my match word is "insurance", also to take care words if they are capitalized and such.

Comment: `'insurance' in 'lifeinsurance'` will return `True`.  Altering `word in title` to `word.lower() in title.lower()` will cover character case.  I mean, if you really want to use a regex, I'm sure there's a solution that will work, but I think it might be a bit complicated for this use case.

Comment: After reading about this a bit I get it, works fine this way.